# Displaying an image with PHP from a database

Tags: php, html, database, image

I have a problem displaying images for URLs that are saved in a database.

This is my HTML source code:

```
<div id="posts">
<img id="images" src="php/getImage.php?id=1">
<footer>            
<a href="php/getImage.php?id=1" download><p>Download</p></a>
</footer>
</div>
```

And my getImage.php file:

```php
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$db = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "DB name");
$sql = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE imageID=$id";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "images/$result";  
?>
```

Comment: how do you store images?? are you storing image in dir and its relative path in db or image as blog in db?

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*`. It's deprecated and not secure! You're mixing `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*`.

Comment: I'm storing the name of the image in my database under the field "image" and trying to output the image by echoing "images/$result" (images/ being the folder I have images saved too).

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems here:

**1)** STOP using `Mysql_` functions and use **ONLY** `mysqli_` functions (or `PDO`) . Mysql_ PHP funtions are deprecated and no longer supported (and hasn't been for 5+ years!). It is insecure and will only get worse.

**2)** Your PHP file is simply `echo`'ing a string, `images/someimagename.jpg`; this is not what an image file is, you need to *output the contents* of this filename string.

**3)** Your current SQL is prone to SQL injection and is currently extremely insecure. Your database can be easily corrupted/abused by nefarious web page visitors.

**4)** Your `mysqli_fetch_array` needs to be assigned to a variable for the values in the array to be used.

**5)** Use single quotes rather than double quotes for your DB authentication so that special characters (such as`$`) - especially in passwords - are not misinterpreted by PHP.

## Solution to the above problems:

```
<?php
// id is assumed to be an integer value.
// This prevents SQL injection and database compromise by forced
// typecasting of the data to integer.
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];

$db = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'DB name');
$sql = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE imageID=".$id." LIMIT 1"; 

// only use mysqli_ functions.
$result=mysqli_query($db, $sql);

// assign to a $variable
$output = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

//The [ relative :( ] URL of the resoure requested:
$file = "images/".$output['image'];

// Before the data is output we need to set the correct header so the 
// browser knows what sort of file to expect.
$image_mime = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($file));    
header("Content-type: " . $image_mime);

// Grab and output the raw data in the filepath stored in the URL.
print readfile($file);

// If this is the end of thefile you should not use a closing PHP tag.   
// ?>
```

If you do not have the [PHP Exif Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php) enabled there are various other (possibly more verbose) ways of ouputting the image type using [`fileinfo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397350/fileinfo-function-php) or [`mime_content_type`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php).

> **PLEASE NOTE:**
> Your image URL is *relative* so, as the file `getImage.php` is in the `php` folder, the image requested will be in the `php/images/<filename>` path. If this is NOT where your images are stored, then you need to adjust your image path URL and make it either correct, or use [absolute HTML pathing](http://docs.worldsecuresystems.com/user-manual/site-design/Pages/understanding-the-difference-between-relative-and-absolute-paths) **which is HIGHLY recommended**.

Answer (score 0):

The code posted with the question has used `mysql_query / mysql_fetch_array` which is deprecated to use in PHP anymore. Even with deprecated `mysql_*` version, this part

```
mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "images/$result";
```

of posted code should be

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC); 
echo "images/".$row["image"];
```

(I haven't tested this code as PHP version in my machine is above 5.5 which doesn't support mysql_* extensions).

Each row requires being fetched from the result (`$result`) of SQL query. From the fetched row (`$row`) each cell can be accessed using the column header (`image`).

Try following code in getimage.php,

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $db = new mysqli("host", "username", "password", "DB name");
    $sql = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE imageID=$id";

    $result=$db->query($sql);

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    echo 'images/'.$row['image'];
?>
```

FYI, mysqli supports both procedural and object-oriented programming paradigm. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php

Comment: put this in you answer. And also you'll need to make the $db an object, don't forget.